# Using VPN and Proxy at the same time

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, encryption

If I have one program run through a proxy then turn on my vpn, will the vpn "override" the proxy? 
The case is, I want all my traffic to be encrypted over the vpn but I want the speed of the proxy in this one program and still be encrypted by the vpn, is this possible? Can I run this one program through the proxy and still have the traffic encrypted through the vpn at the same time or will the program using the proxy be unencrypted?

Second question, any good program I can use to analyze my network traffic so I can test this myself?

Answer (score 3):

> I have one program run through a proxy then turn on my vpn, will the
>   vpn "override" the proxy?

No, The VPN is more like a **Network Adapter** (or a virtual "network card" if you like). So if the VPN is on it is possible for the proxy traffic to go through the VPN (not the other way round - at least not when you do it on the same machine).

> The case is, I want all my traffic to be encrypted over the vpn but I
>   want the speed of the proxy in this one program and still be encrypted
>   by the vpn, is this possible?

If you insist on using the VPN, then the **final** network speed that you get would be limited by VPN and the speed will be at slower of the two speeds (and in practice, the final speed you end up with  will be much slower than either the VPN or the proxy alone).

> Can I run this one program through the proxy and still have the
>   traffic encrypted through the vpn at the same time or will the program
>   using the proxy be unencrypted?

As I gave the example earlier, your VPN is like another "Network Card" (LAN Interface) except that its virtual. Thats the best analogy that I can give.
Therefore, you can use a proxy or *even another VPN* (tunnel within a tunnel) for all the traffic from your computer.

This is pretty much standard and we do it sometimes within larger organizations (for added security).

However the price you would pay with would be a drop in the speed of the connection, and this gets worse the more VPNs/Proxies you put in the way of the traffic.

So in other words, if are trying to add a proxy for "speed", no, it will not solve the problem since the **limitig factor will be the *SLOWEST passage-way the traffic encounters in its way to the destination*** (SO if the VPN has a lower speed, it would not make the fact that you added a proxy to the setup, any faster).

> Second question, any good program I can use to analyze my network
>   traffic so I can test this myself?

There are many tools. For a non-professional the easiest but at the same time, a tool that that would give you significant insight into the process would be [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

If you really want to dig deep, then [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is one of the tools used by professionals.

You did not mention the platform that you are on, but here's a [list of other tools](https://techtalk.gfi.com/the-top-20-free-network-monitoring-and-analysis-tools-for-sys-admins/) if you do not like the two tools that I mentioned above.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the actual question asked.
other answer tell a different story

Answer (score 3):

Anyone saying you can't is misinformed.  You can do it.

I run a proxy and a VPN both at home.  I actually run two VPNs and a proxy all at the same time.

The proxy creates a routing table that allows me to connect to my home network.  I can be outside of my 192.168.2.x network and navigate through the browser to my home servers.  I also have a proxy running on 192.168.2.2:1024.  My Laptop uses the normal internet it's located on at the time to route trafic by default unless the ip is in the VPN subnet or the  program is configured  to use the proxy (which is in  the vpn subnet)

I then use the socks5 proxy in specific programs that i want routed through my home network and through the VPN.

This setup allows me to do a few things.

Traffic in my work VPN subnet goes through work VPN
Traffic in my home vpn subnet goes to  my home VPN
Individual programs that allow you to change their proxy settings can be routed through my home vpn via the proxy.

Comment: The only right answer posted. Good job clearly explaining.

Comment: This is a good answer because it positions other scenarios that the user is not asking about but people finding this post will want to know.
Sorry this is not the "Only right answer"...
If you read the question, it specifically says the user wants speed of proxy but encrypted through VPN. This is not possible! Cannot have cake and eat it too situation...
The moment you want encryption it is always going to be slower the very nature of more processing of the encryption.
proxy hides you and still gives you the speed but not the encryption.
other previous answers answer this better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, yes, the vpn setting will override the setting of proxy. Therefore you cannot use both proxy and VPN at the same time. The reason of the slower speed of VPN is due mainly due to the encryption between the VPN client and VPN server. So you simply cannot enjoy the speed of proxy while the data encrypted by VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe you CAN use both. The VPN connection will grab all of your network traffic and route it to the exiting VPN server while at the same time, your proxied traffic will travel through your VPN tunnel, exit at the exit server, then connect to the proxy server you have setup.

Comment: What is the basis for your belief? Have you done this? Can you refer to a specification or a published paper that supports your statement?